# how to use foreach loop two times in laravel5

Tags: laravel-5

IN laravel 5 how to use  two  foreach loop to retrive the data from database with two different tables and join the two table show a view

via
 -controller
 -Routers

let me know any democode is there please rply it...

Comment: Did you heard about DataTable ?

Comment: Or joins, for that matter... https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins

Comment: property_details table and agent_details table both the unique column state how to join the both and featch the data from database

Answer (score 0):

Just use basic eloquent relationship in laravel. For example I have 2 tables named categories and subcategories. After you set an id (for example categoryId) in your subcategories table, you can create a function in category model like :

```
public function categories(){
return $this->hasMany('App\subcategory');}
```

and a function in subcategory model like :

```
public function subcategories(){
return $this->belongsTo('App\category');}
```

This code means for every category has many subcategories, and for every subcategory you can only have 1 category.
And in your controller you can just call each function anytime, for example :

```
$category = Category::first();
$subcategories = $category->subcategories();
```

Inside $subcategories you will have every instance of subcategories for your first category. Then you can just use @foreach loop in your view to display the result. Hope this helps.